# Are all infinite discrete topological spaces homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Is it possible to show that if $X$ and $Y$ are two infinite sets, with $X\neq Y$, and $T_X=(X,2^X)$, $T_Y=(Y,2^Y)$ being their disctete topologies, respectively, then:
$$T_X\cong T_Y$$
(Isomorphism sign $\cong$ meaning Homeomoprhism)?

Comment: Consider $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You need a condition: $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic as discrete spaces iff they are equipollent (i.e., iff their is a bijection between the two sets).